# Find xml-tag with given value

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I have an XML-file with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<application name="MyApp">
    <component name="MyComponent">
        <setting>
            <name>mySetting</name>
            <value>myValue</value>
        </setting>
    </component>
</application>
```

Now I want to select that setting (only one single) within `MyComponent` that has the name `mySetting`. I tried `root.findall('./application/component/[@name="mySetting"]')` but that gave me `NoneType`.

EDIT: current code looks like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <application>
        <component name="MyComponent">
            <setting>
                <name>mySetting</name>
                <value>myValue</value>
            </setting>
        </component>
    </application>"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
settings = root.findall('./component/setting')
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Seems like you are missing 'setting' in your xpath request

Comment: @mguijarr You ment `root.findall('./application/component/setting/[@name="mySetting"]')`? Doesn´t work either. But apparently I don´t even get any result from `root.findall('./application/')`

Comment: Try with '//application'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer due to @mguijarr which was much easier as I expected ommiting the root-node from the xPath:

```
root.findall('./component[@name="MyComponent"]/setting[name="mySetting"]')
```